# How to make Saturn ring bigger (or any torus)

Tags: materials

Is possible to make Saturn ring bigger

Screenshot

[image: Text]

I wanted to make the ring bigger

Comment: if you want to make it thicker, switch to Edit mode, select all, press Alt S and drag

Comment: @moonboots what is edit mode?

Comment: it's the mode where you can change the mesh, select the ring and press Tab

Comment: yeah, but alt-s and tab to change to edit mode are 3 (THREEEEEEE) keystrokes. Task was : with the fewest keystrokes....!! Moonboots: sorry, i have no picture for you. And also no recall for you....so sorrrrrrry!!!!

Comment: @Chris nvm, don't delete your answer

Comment: @Chris well in that case, call Chris, he's going to python you the thickenyourtorus addon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select the torus, press <kbd>S</kbd> and move your mouse.

[image]

Comment: I don't have any mouse in my house. Does it work with a cat?

Comment: @moonboots really?

Comment: actually, yes, my parents have some, but they trap them

Comment: @moonboots they trap mice or cats?

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady you get a cat ass trophy if you trap enough cats.

Comment: @moonboots must you always treat Chris like this!?!?! LOL

Comment: @james_t Chris is my challenger, I need to destroy him!!!!

Comment: @Markus von Broady they trap mice unfortunately   :/  (true story)

Answer (score 5):

If we define:

$O$ - origin

$A$ - a vertex laying on the X axis, with the smallest positive X value

$B$ - a vertex laying on the X axis, with the largest positive X value

$I$ - a point exactly halfway between A and B

[image]

To change the torus'es major radius $|OI|$, without changing the torus'es minor radius $|IA| = |IB|$:

0. Enable *Edit Mesh Tools* add-on.
1. In *Edit Mode* select both $A$ and $B$ vertices, <kbd>F</kbd> to create an edge connecting them.
2. In <kbd>N</kbd> *Numbers Panel*, *Edit* tab, click on *Edge Tools > Set Edge Length*.
3. Hover your **digital** mouse over *Target Length* field, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> to copy the value, click outside the popup window **to avoid resizing**.
4. <kbd>A</kbd> *Select All*, <kbd>S</kbd> scale however you want (within reason).
5. Select only the edge created in p. 1.
6. Repeat p. 2.
7. Click on the *Target Length* field, <kbd>Home</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>-</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd> (calculating the difference).
8. Repeat p. 3.
9. Remove the edge created in p. 1.
10. <kbd>A</kbd> *Select All*, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> to Starve/Feed, click.
11. In the popup, click on the *Offset* field, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>/</kbd>, <kbd>2</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

[image]

I fear it's not as simple as Chris'es solution.

Comment: I don't understand. But I will test this later

Comment: I would always use this solution, the answer from @Chris is so mundane. By the way, do you have a digital cat as well?

Comment: What is "Enable Edit Mesh Tools add-on."

Comment: @Fmbalbuena Edit > Preferences... Add-ons