# How to make a hoop simply...yes it seems an easy question but wait

Tags: bevel

Is there a way I can make a hoop, say, that has a major diameter of 40 mm and has a 2 mm diameter circular profile?

Bevel flattens the sides of the profile and changes the major diameter of the item that is bevelled.

I can’t seem to find a way to extrude along a path and get what I am after.

In addition, the bevel size doesn’t appear to have anything to do with the size of the profile. For example, if I want the hoop to have a 2 mm diameter boundary profile, the bez circle I need to create is 60, 70, 80 mm!

Even then it creates an ellipse and not a circle.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Hi :). Keep in mind that if you scale a bezier circle, the bevel size is affected: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/250716/78972

Comment: I forgot to ask if you're looking for a solution with curves or meshes? My answer assumed meshes.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [How to make Saturn ring bigger (or any torus)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/250042/60486) (which is a duplicate of [How do I scale a Torus's minor radius?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/121031/60486))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

//EDIT: I made the assumption you wanted to create a mesh. If you want a curve solution, you'll find it at the end.

//2. EDIT: Sorry I'm an idiot I somehow thought you wrote circular profile with a diameter of 4 mm... I'll correct the values for the 2 mm version, but the images are still for a diameter of 4 mm.

**Mesh version:** A hoop with a circular profile? So you mean what is usually called a torus? What about just adding a torus with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> > *Mesh* > *Torus*?

Then set *Major Radius* to 20 mm and *Minor Radius* to 1 mm in *Dimension Mode* > *Major/Minor* or maybe *Exterior Radius* to 20 mm and *Interior Radius* to 18 mm in *Exterior/Interior* mode?

Whereas the *Major/Minor* example I gave here actually creates an overall diameter of 42 mm instead of 40 mm, I don't know if you want 40 mm overall dimensions or 40 mm from one center of the circular profile to the opposite profile's center.

About the bevel dimensions: I guess you have scaled the object in *Object Mode* and didn't apply the scale: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> > *Apply* > *Scale*.

[image: major/minor]

[image: exterior/interior]

**Curve version:** If you're instead going to do this with curves, add a curve circle with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> > *Curve* > *Circle*. Set the *Radius* to 20 mm and under *Object Data Properties* > *Geometry* > *Bevel* set a *Depth* of 1 mm. This also results in an overall width of 42 mm because the radius goes from one profile center to the opposite. If you want an overall width of 40 mm, set the *Radius* to 19 mm.

[image: curve circle]

**Excursion:** Comparing *Dimensions Mode* options of the *Torus*, *Major/Minor* and *Exterior/Interior*.

In both modes I created a torus object which is overall 10 m wide in diameter and has a circular ring profile with a diameter of 2 m.

*Major/Minor* mode:

[image: maj/min]

*Exterior/Interior* mode:

[image: ext/int]

Comment: torus was the best way to go i think, thankyou very much. i gave up on torus in the past because i could work out how to set major and minor diameters..

Comment: @TimN Did you get a better understanding of the Torus object now or should I add some schematics ?

Answer (score 6):

And here's an answer regarding curves

Use *Bevel > Depth* to set a circular profile radius
Use *Geometry > Offset* to correct your circle size back to 40mm

[image]

Comment: Oh, of course, the _Offset_ is a good idea. Better than mine with adjusting the radius beforehand. But you set the Bevel radius, not diameter.

Comment: Yo thanks :). I still find blender a bit confusing, not always clear what's radius and diameter

Comment: Most of the time it's radius... and except for the bevel depth it's mostly written down somewhere. Maybe it's easy or more natural to me because when I'm dealing with circular shapes outside of Blender I usually work with the radius, too.